Convert to Chomsky normal form
Let a context-free language be specified by its production rules and start symbol, e.g.
S -> AbB | C
C -> b | c
B -> AA | AC
A -> a | ε

Here and in the rest of this task nonterminals are uppercase letters and terminals are lowercase letters. A Chomsky normal form for this language generates the same words, but every production rule is either of the form

A -> BC with B,C not the start symbol
A -> a
S -> ε, only allowed if the language contains the empty word ε

Such a normal form always exists for every context-free language. One way to achieve this transformation follows:

Given a start symbol T, make a new start symbol S distinct from all existing nonterminals and add a rule S -> T.
For every terminal r for which there is a rule whose RHS contains it not alone, make a new nonterminal R, a new rule R -> r and replace all instances of r in the RHSs of said rules by R.
Now all rules producing more than one symbol produce nonterminals only. For each such rule producing at least three nonterminals, e.g. A -> BCDE, make new nonterminals and replace the rule by new rules producing the same nonterminal sequence, but only one new one at a time:

A -> BX
X -> CY
Y -> DE


Now all rules producing more than one symbol are of the form A -> BC as the normal form requires. Consider the set of all "nullable" nonterminals that can derive ε – if A -> ε is present, or A -> BC is present with B,C nullable, then A is nullable. For each rule with nullable nonterminals (e.g. M,N) add new ones with said nonterminals omitted in all possible ways:




Rule
Additions




A -> M
A -> ε


A -> MB
A -> B


A -> CN
A -> C


A -> MN
A -> M, A -> N, A -> ε



Then delete all rules of the form A -> ε where A is not the start symbol.

Now no production except S -> ε can generate ε. The last step deals with unit rules of the form A -> B: for each such rule and each other rule of the form B -> CD (not a unit rule) add rule A -> CD, then remove A -> B. The resulting grammar is in Chomsky normal form.

Task
Given production rules for a context-free language, output production rules in Chomsky normal form that generate the same language. You do not have to follow the algorithm above and the normal form produced may have duplicate rules and irreducible nonterminals (those not on the LHS of any production rule).
You may use any reasonable format for the production rules, terminals, nonterminals and start symbol. One possible format represents the produced words as lists of integers, with the start symbol 0, positive integers as terminals and nonpositive integers as nonterminals.
Examples
The Dyck language of corectly nested ud pairs
S -> uSdS | ε

has a Chomsky normal form (among others)
S -> ε
S,T -> UK | UL | UD
U -> u
D -> d
K -> TL | TD 
L -> DT

The language of odd-length palindromes over abc
S -> aSa | bSb | cSc | a | b | c

has a Chomsky normal form
S,T -> a | b | c | AU | BV | CW
U -> TA
V -> TB
W -> TC
A -> a
B -> b
C -> c


The grammar at the top of this task has a Chomsky normal form of (thanks to comments)
S -> AX | DB | b | c
A -> a
B -> AA | a | AC | b | c
C -> b | c
X -> DB | b
D -> b


I applied the algorithm for the first language to get S -> T; T -> AX | B'B | b | c; A -> a; B -> AA | a | AC | b | c; C -> b | c; X -> B'B | b; B' -> b

Surely S -> T is a unit rule and so should not appear in the output?

@Neil Easily fixed though.

GNU sed -E, 461 457 449 bytes
s/^/;0,q/
:q
s/q/qq/g
t3
:3
s/(,\w+)(,\w+,\w+)(.*)/\1,q\3;q\2/
tq
s/(.*)(;(q+)z)/\3\1/
:4
s/^(q+)\>(.*);((\w+)(,\1(,\w+)|(,\w+),\1))\>/\1\2%\3;\4\6\7/
t4
s/^(q+)\>(.*);((\w+),\1)\>/\1\2%\3;\4z/
t4
s/^q+//
y/%/;/
t3
s/;(q+,q+,\w+)/<\1/g
s/(.*);(q+,q+)/\2\1/
:g
s/^((q+),(q+))\>(.*);(\3(,\w+(,\w+)?))/\1;\2\6\4<\5/
tg
s/^q+,q+//
y/</;/
t3
s/,(a+,)/%\1/g
s/(,q+),a/\1%a/g
s/(.*)(%a+)/q\2&/
:s
s/^q(%a+)\>(.*)\1\>/q\1\2,q/
ts
s/^q%(a+)/;q,\1/
s/%/,/g
tq

Try it online!
Usage
One-line input. Unary state and unary alphabet.
Input := Rule*
Rule := ";" State RewriteList
State := "q"+
RewriteList := ( "," ( State | Alphabet) )+ | Empty
Alphabet:= "a"+
Empty := "z"

One letter state "q" considered to be initial state of input; the output additionally uses "0" to represent initial.
For example if you have the language
S -> AbB | C
C -> b | c
B -> AA | AC
A -> a | ε

you need to translate into this:
;q,qq,aa,qqq;q,qqqq;qqqq,aa;qqqq,aaa;qqq,qq,qq;qqq,qq,qqqq;qq,a;qqz

States S, A, B, C are translated into q, qq, qqq, qqqq respectively; similar for alphabets a, b, c.
Ungolfed 461 bytes answer
I tried with in order of step 1, 3, 4, 5, 2.
Reading hint: I named alphabet labels taken from the qwerty keyboard;
# step 1
s/^/;0,q/

# rename every state; new state q can be introduced
:q
# s/\<q/qq/g # readable alternative
s/q/qq/g
t3

# step 3
:3
s/(,\w+)(,\w+,\w+)(.*)/\1,q\3;q\2/
tq

:r
# step 4
# choose a nullable state
s/(.*)(;(q+)z)/\3\1/
Tw

# add nullable state rules
:4
s/^(q+)\>(.*);((\w+)(,\1(,\w+)|(,\w+),\1))\>/\1\2%\3;\4\6\7/
t4
s/^(q+)\>(.*);((\w+),\1)\>/\1\2%\3;\4z/
t4

# step 4 done for that state
s/q+//
y/%/;/
tr

# step 5
# protect every A -> BC
:w
s/;(q+,q+,\w+)/<\1/g

# choose one A -> B
s/(.*);(q+,q+)/\2\1/

# no need to unprotect A -> BC
# if A -> B and B -> ... add A -> ...
:g
s/^((q+),(q+))\>(.*);(\3(,\w+(,\w+)?))/\1;\2\6\4<\5/
tg

# remove A -> B
s/^q+,q+//

# end of step 5 or just removed A -> B
y/</;/
tw

# step 2
# mark every alphabet a in A -> Ba and A -> aB
s/,(a+,)/%\1/g
s/(,q+),(a+)/\1%\2/g

# choose one alphabet
s/(.*)(%a+)/q\2&/

# now rewrite rules
:s
s/^q(%a+)\>(.*)\1\>/q\1\2,q/
ts
s/^q%(a+)/;q,\1/

# still having any?
s/%/,/g
tq # to be able to get more states

# COMPLETED!
# some rules are duplicated but whatever

Try it online!

Charcoal, 200 bytes
ＵＭθＥιＥλ∨νＬθ⊞θ§θ⁰§≔θ⁰⟦⟦⊖Ｌθ⟧⟧Ｗ⌊ＥΦＥθΦκ∧›Ｌμ¹‹⌊μ⁰κ⌊Ｅκ⌊μ«ＵＭθＥκＥμ⎇⁼ξιＬθξ⊞θ⟦⟦ι⟧⟧»Ｗ⌊ΦＥθ⌊Φκ›Ｌμ²κ«⊞θ⟦⮌Ｅ²⊟ι⟧⊞ι⊖Ｌθ»ＷΦ⁻Ｅθλυ⊙§θκ¬⁻μυＦι⊞υκＵＭθΦιλＦ№υ⁰⊞§θ⁰⟦⟧ＦθＦΦι⁼Ｌκ²ＦΦ²№υ§κλ⊞ιΦκ⁻νλＷ⌊ΣＥθΦκ∧⁼Ｌμ¹›⌊μ⁰ＵＭθ⁺⁻κ⟦ι⟧⎇№κι§θ⌊ι⟦⟧⭆¹θ

Attempt This Online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as an array of arrays of rules where index 0 represents the start symbol and rules contain positive integers for nonterminals and negative integers for terminals. Explanation:
ＵＭθＥιＥλ∨νＬθ⊞θ§θ⁰§≔θ⁰⟦⟦⊖Ｌθ⟧⟧

Renumber the start symbol and add a production from 0 to the new symbol.
Ｗ⌊ＥΦＥθΦκ∧›Ｌμ¹‹⌊μ⁰κ⌊Ｅκ⌊μ

While rules exist that contain terminals but aren't of normal form, ...
«ＵＭθＥκＥμ⎇⁼ξιＬθξ⊞θ⟦⟦ι⟧⟧»

... add a new nonterminal with a production to the terminal and rename all uses of that terminal to the new nonterminal.
Ｗ⌊ΦＥθ⌊Φκ›Ｌμ²κ

While a rule exists with more than two nonterminals...
«⊞θ⟦⮌Ｅ²⊟ι⟧⊞ι⊖Ｌθ»

... add a new nonterminal for the last two nonterminals in that rule and update the rule to use that nonterminal instead.
ＷΦ⁻Ｅθλυ⊙§θκ¬⁻μυＦι⊞υκ

Determine which nonterminals are nullable.
ＵＭθΦιλ

Remove all empty productions.
Ｆ№υ⁰⊞§θ⁰⟦⟧

If the start symbol is nullable then add in an empty production.
ＦθＦΦι⁼Ｌκ²ＦΦ²№υ§κλ⊞ιΦκ⁻νλ

For each rule that contains a nullable nonterminal, add a rule with that nonterminal removed.
Ｗ⌊ΣＥθΦκ∧⁼Ｌμ¹›⌊μ⁰

While a unit rule exists...
ＵＭθ⁺⁻κ⟦ι⟧⎇№κι§θ⌊ι⟦⟧

... update all of the productions that include it to include the rules for its nonterminal instead.
⭆¹θ

Output the final list of productions.
The given example
S -> AbB | C
A -> a | ε
B -> AA | AC
C -> b | c

is represented by the following input array:
[
 [[1, -2, 2], [3]],
 [[-1], []],
 [[1, 1], [1, 3]],
 [[-2], [-3]]]
]

The resulting normal form is
[
 [[1, 6], [-3], [-2], [5, 2], [-2]],
 [[-1]],
 [[1, 1], [1, 3], [-1], [-3], [-2]],
 [[-3], [-2]],
 [[1, 6], [-3], [-2], [5, 2], [-2]],
 [[-2]],
 [[5, 2], [-2]]
]

which can be interpreted as:
S -> AF | c | b | EB | b
A -> a
B -> AA | AC | a | c | b
C -> c | b
D -> AF | c | b | EB | b
E -> b
F -> EB | b


Python3, 911 bytes
import string as S
from itertools import*
L=str.islower
H=lambda x:x.replace('S','T')
V=product
def P(T,G):
 q,s=[b for a,b in G if a==T],[]
 for i in q:
  if''==i:return 1
  for j in map(''.join,V(*[[t]if L(t)else[b for a,b in G if a==t]for t in i])):
   if j==''or not any({*k}=={*j}for k in s):q+=[j];s+=[j]
 return 0
def f(g):
 g=[(H(a),H(b))for a,b in g]
 s,d=[*{*S.ascii_uppercase}-{a for a,_ in g}-{'S'}],{}
 G,N=[],[]
 for a,b in g:
  if all(L(i)for i in b):G+=[(a,b)]
  else:
   n=''
   for i in b:
    if L(i):G+=[(t:=(d.get(i)or s.pop()),i)];d[i]=t;i=t
    n+=i
   N+=[(a,n)]
 for a,b in N:
  if len(b)<3:G+=[(a,b)];continue
  G+=[(a,b[0]+(i:=s.pop()))];N+=[(i,b[1:])]
 K=[]
 G={*G}
 for a,b in G:
  if''!=b:K+=[(a,''.join(j))for j in V(*[[t]+['']*P(t,G)for t in b])]
 F,T=[],[*{*G,*K}]
 for a,b in T:
  if len(b)==1 and not L(b):T+=[(a,B)for A,B in T if A==b]
  else:F+=[(a,b)]
 return [('S','T')]+F

Try it online!

905 bytes
